# Conditional wrapping in Angular 6 html

Tags: angular

I have a component and I defined array of objects with dates inside

```
calendarDates = [
 {date: "2018-11-01"}, 
 {date: "2018-11-02"}, 
 {date: "2018-11-03"}, 
 {...},
 {date: "2018-12-01"}, 
 {date: "2018-12-02"}, 
 {date: "2018-12-03"}, 
 {date: "2018-12-04"}, 
 {...},
 {date: "2019-01-01"},
 {date: "2019-01-02"},
 {...}
 ]
```

My objective is to loop through calendarDates in component HTML and categorized it in the following manner:

```
 //<div *ngFor='let calendarDate of calendarDates'>
   <div class='month'>
     <div class='week'>
       <div class='date'>{{calendarDate.date}}</div>
       <div class='date'>{{calendarDate.date}}</div>
       <div class='date'>{{calendarDate.date}}</div>
       ...
     </div>
     <div class='week'>
       <div class='date'>{{calendarDate.date}}</div>
       ...
     </div>
     ...
  </div>
   <div class='month'>
     <div class='week'>
       <div class='date'>{{calendarDate.date}}</div>
       <div class='date'>{{calendarDate.date}}</div>
       <div class='date'>{{calendarDate.date}}</div>
       ...
     </div>
     <div class='week'>
       <div class='date'>{{calendarDate.date}}</div>
       ...
     </div>
     ...
  </div>
//</div>
```

For this I created two functions:

```
  dateIsMonday(date) {
    if (new Date(date).getDay() === 1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  dateIsFirstDayOfMonth(date) {
    if (new Date(date).getDate() === 1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

With this and some additional functions I would be able to categorize it but what I am not sure if it's possible if and how to create the wrappers:  How to create  only if dateIsFirstDayOfMonth() is true and then the following dates from the same month how can I add it inside? I would prefer this angular way in html but if this is not possible, does angular have any alternatives?

PS: I am not sure if the title is sync with the question so please help to edit if not.

Comment: You're trying to do too much things in the view. If your view needs to display a list of months, each containing a list of weeks, each containing a list of dates, then create that hirarchical structure in your component, using all the power of TypeScript, and just use nested ngFor in the view to display this hierarchical structure.

Comment: I might add there a couple of things like is_available, price... so I hoped I could simply generate it in the html code and then add more things when the data will be available - without the complication of hierarchical structure @JBNizet

Comment: That doesn't change anything. You'll just arrange bigger objects in the same structure. The hierarchical structure is not a complication. it's a simplification. Whatever you do, you need that hierarchical structure. It's just way harder to create it in the view than in the component, because TypeScript is way more powerful to create an algorithm than HTML is.